# Swift - App Delegate not passing data

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, url-scheme

I'm developing an App that it's data is from a URL, here's a sample code that I'm using
AppDelegate.swift

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var fromUrl: String!


    func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject)-> Bool {

            print("Host: \(url.host!)")
            self.fromUrl = url.host!

            return true
    }
```

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let appDelegate = AppDelegate()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print(appDelegate.fromUrl)

    }
```

It's is logging the `url.host` from app delegate. But when i try to log the value of `fromUrl` from the `ViewController.swift` it's returning `nil`. What do you think seems to be the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare `let appDelegate = AppDelegate()` in `ViewController` you are actually instantiating another instance of `AppDelegate`. That is not the same instance that you are using as you actual `ApplicationDelegate`. Try getting that reference by using:

```
if let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate {
    print(appDelegate.fromUrl)
}
```